# Parse JSON Array without Key in Android

Tags: android, arrays, json

How would I parse an array like the following in Android?

```
[
 5,
 10,
 15,
 20
]
```

As you can see, there is no key defining the array, like other example arrays have, such as this:

```
{
 "items": [
   5,
   10,
   15
   ]
}
```

For the second array, I can easily make a `JSONObject` and just use:

```
JSONArray itemArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items")
```

But, as is obvious, there is no key for the first array. So how would one go about this? Is it even possible with standard Android libraries?

Comment: had you found the solution ?

Comment: Yep, the accepted answer has it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30586115/2676875

Comment: How can i implement this with retrofit Can you please help

Comment: I would open a new question for the specific use case of `retrofit`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you tried doing this?

```
try {
    // jsonString is a string variable that holds the JSON 
    JSONArray itemArray=new JSONArray(jsonString);
    for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++) {
        int value=itemArray.getInt(i);
        Log.e("json", i+"="+value);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Would this not parse the second JSON file? I apologize if my question was written in a confusing way. I want to parse the first JSON file, the one without the "items" key. Would this mean that my `JSONArray` would just be set to the JSON file that I am getting?

Comment: Yes, this would parse the second JSON file. I'm sorry I didn't understand your question. To get the first JSONArray, you would do something like `JSONArray itemArray=new JSONArray(yourstringname);` where `yourstringname` is a String variable that holds your JSON file(I'm assuming it's a string) and then the rest will be the same.

Comment: Perfect, just tried it and it works as intended. If you wouldn't mind, could you modify your answer so it matches the question for future readers/reference? I'll accept it after that.

Answer (score -2):

Consider Foreach version:

```
try {
    JSONArray itemArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
    for (var item : itemArray) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here you can directly access the data in json array.

```
JSONArray itemArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

for(int i=0;i<itemarray.length;i++)

{

int i = Integer.ParseInt(itemarray.get(i));

Log.i("Value is:::",""+i);

}
```

Comment: read the question again, response with no key need to be handles here.