# Parse JSON without key in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

How can I parse this array without a key before the square brackets?

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "model": "RAV 4",
        "brand": "Toyota"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "model": "A6",
        "brand": "Audi"
    }
]
```

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586069/parse-json-array-without-key-in-android), but for Android.

Comment: The json does have keys, it simply an array of jsons. loop through it and parse it

Comment: Arrays are accessed by index, there are two items in the array, at index 0 the dictionary with `id = 2` and at index 1 the dictionary with `id = 1`. Just enumerate the array.

Comment: @kye It's an array of dictionaries, not an array of jsons. You do not need to loop and parse.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the correct

Comment: @rmaddy Hi, I always thought json and dictionary refers to the same thing. If it's not an array of jsons, then how does an array of jsons looks like?

Comment: @JLT JSON is a textual representation of data. An array is a list. A dictionary is a collection of key-value pairs.  As it happens, JSON data is made up of arrays and dictionaries in whatever possible structure is appropriate for the data. The JSON data presented in the question happens to be an array of dictionaries. No one would call it an array of JSON.

Comment: @rmaddy ahh, understood. Thank you very much!

Comment: How can we do this in swift5?

Answer (score 3):

Just parse it using NSJSONSerialization as normal, and cast the result as an array of `[String:AnyObject]` dictionaries.

So, something like:

```
if let json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(yourLoadedNSData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0))) as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
    print(json.count) // Should be 2, based on your sample json above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Update for Swift 3***

```
if let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions(rawValue: 0))) as? [String] {
// do stuff here
}
```

Just in case of :)