# Parse JSON Array without key using Dart

Tags: arrays, json, dart, flutter

I can't seems to find a solution to parse a json array without key using Dart language. All i can find is by using Java. I need to parse something like this..

```
[
 5,
 10,
 15,
 20
]
```

Java solution is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586069/parse-json-array-without-key-in-android)

Please inform me if I have duplicate question. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `json.decode` as normal, for example:

```
List<dynamic> l = json.decode('[5, 10, 15, 20]');
```

It happens that the members of `l` will all be `int`s

Comment: Thanks! this is working. But I have another problem parsing nested arrays, if you could check this question of mine [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51978610/parse-nested-json-array-and-put-it-in-a-model-class-using-dart-language)

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';
void main() {
  var x = "[ 5, \n 10, \n15\n, 20]";
  var b = jsonDecode(x);
  print(b[3]); //prints 20

}
```

- [DartPad Example](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/3b18d74a619300a304fe1ebfaf1198b1)
- [Official docs](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/library-tour#dartconvert---decoding-and-encoding-json-utf-8-and-more)

Comment: Thanks Sir!.. I will try this.

Comment: Hi sir can you check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51978610/parse-nested-json-array-and-put-it-in-a-model-class-using-dart-language) out too? it's the same problem but parsing nested json arrays into model class.