# Parse Nested JSON Array and put it in a Model class using Dart Language

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, dart, flutter

In relation to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977112/parse-json-array-without-key-using-dart)

I want to parse a JSON array without a key within JSON array and put it in a Model class.

here is a JSON Array that I want to parse.

```
[
    {
        "pk": 100,
        "user": 5,
        "name": "Flutter",
        "details": "Fluttery",
        "images": [
            89,
            88,
            87,
            86
        ],
        "priority": 5
    },
    {
        "pk": 99,
        "user": 5,
        "name": "",
        "details": "h",
        "images": [],
        "priority": 5
    },
    {
        "pk": 98,
        "user": 5,
        "name": "Flutter",
        "details": "Fluttery",
        "images": [
            85
        ],
        "priority": 5
    },
]
```

I have successfully parse the main Array but I cannot parse the `images` key that contains an array of integers. I want to put it into Model class. please help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this way:

```
    final jsonList = json.decode(response.body) as List;
    final userList = jsonList.map((map) => User.fromJson(map)).toList();
```

User class

```
        class User {
          final int pk;
          final String name;
          final List<int> images;

          User._({this.pk, this.name, this.images});

          factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
            return new User._(
                pk: json['pk'],
                name: json['name'],
                images:  (json['images'] as List).map((map) => int.parse("$map")).toList());
          }
        }
```

**Print your data**

```
    for (var i = 0; i < userList.length; i++) { 
       print(userList[i].name);
       final imageList = userList[i].images;
       for (var j = 0 ; j < imageList.length; j++){
          print("image: ${imageList[j]}");
       }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks you! i will try this solution and will get back here asap. :)

Comment: It works! but how to I call the images using nested for loop? I used this to call the name.
`for (var i = 0; i < userList.length; i++) { print(userList[i].name);}`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please refer **Serializing JSON manually using dart:convert** section [here](https://flutter.io/json/). If you stilling face issues, please post the error/difficulties.

Comment: cannot pass the decoded json in `Map` because the result using json.decode(result) is an Arrray.