# Java/Android: Parse JSON without single strings in Array

Tags: java, android, json

I want to parse JSON which looks like this:

```
{
 "A": [
  [
    "content1"
  ],
  [
    "content2"
  ]
 ]
}
```

I need content1 and content2 as a String.

What I tried

```
String content = object.getString("A");
```

but with this I get a String which includes content1 and content2.
I need it seperated because I add it to GridView later.

This is not a duplicate of the question which is marked, look at the JSON it is different.

Comment: that is invalid json

Comment: There was a `]` missed, I added it.

Comment: Use a json library like [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) then deserialize to an object that you can call a custom getter on.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `object.getJSONArray("A")`, store it in some variable.

```
JSONArray someArray = object.getJSONArray("A");
```

and than you can traverse through `JSONArray` to get its values

Comment: Okay but I have to define [0] [1] etc? The problem is there can be a lot of Arrays and not only one or two.

Comment: If it is array you can use for loop for that, if it is object you can access it with `key` name

Comment: @Hannes jsonarray is similar to normal arrays. You can use a normal for loop to iterate through it

Comment: @Hannes check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30586115/7666442

Comment: I receive it as single array now. Should I remove `["` and `"]` manually?