# How to parse Json Arrays inside Json Arrays without key

Tags: android, arrays, json, jsonparser

Hi I am using json parsing, Following is my json response. Can any one help me with parsing,

```
{"success":

"{"mydata":

[
["Ramesh","Architect","Surat","1","2011/04/25","$123,123"], 
["Suresh Ram","Accountant","Amdavad","2","2011/07/25","$121,121"],
["Naresh","Author","Up","3","2009/01/12","$76,000"],

........
```

My confusion is regarding parsing, response is very complex to parse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON Array without Key in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586069/parse-json-array-without-key-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can get success json object easily, so i am directly using `jobSuccess` here.

```
   ArrayList<DataModel> arrDataModel=new ArrayList<DataModel>();
        try {
            JSONArray jarMyData=jobSuccess.getJSONArray("mydata");
            for (int i = 0; i < jarMyData.length(); i++) {
                JSONArray jar = jarMyData.getJSONArray(i);

                    DataModel dataModel=new DataModel();
                    dataModel.name=jar.getString(0);
                    dataModel.occupation=jar.getString(1);
                    dataModel.place=jar.getString(2);
                    dataModel.id=jar.getString(3);
                    dataModel.date=jar.getString(4);
                    dataModel.price=jar.getString(5);
                    arrDataModel.add(dataModel);
            }
        }catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.d("JSONException",e.toString());
        }
```

You can create model class like this:

```
public class DataModel {
    String name, occupation, place, id, date, price;
}
```

Note: i am not sure about fields name, so change their name according to your need.

**Update**
To get `jobSuccess` you need to :

```
String response="your json response in string format";
JSONObject jobSuccess=new JSONObject(response).getJSONObject("success");
```

**Update 2**

```
  // response is the json object you received from volley
            jobSuccess=response.getJSONObject("TABLE_DATA");

            ArrayList<DataModel> arrDataModel=new ArrayList<DataModel>();
            try {
// **Change below statement only**
                JSONArray jarMyData=new JSONObject(jobSuccess.getString("TABLE_DATA"));
                for (int i = 0; i < jarMyData.length(); i++) {
                    JSONArray jar = jarMyData.getJSONArray(i);

                        DataModel dataModel=new DataModel();
                        dataModel.name=jar.getString(0);
                        dataModel.occupation=jar.getString(1);
                        dataModel.place=jar.getString(2);
                        dataModel.id=jar.getString(3);
                        dataModel.date=jar.getString(4);
                        dataModel.price=jar.getString(5);
                        arrDataModel.add(dataModel);
                }
            }catch (JSONException e)
            {
                Log.d("JSONException",e.toString());
            }
```

**Update Latest**
You need to change this:

```
JSONObject jobSuccess=response.getJSONObject("TABLE_DATA");
```

with this:

```
JSONArray jarMyData=new JSONObject(jobSuccess.getString("TABLE_DATA"));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but will you help me with create model class for that

Comment: what is jobsucess

Comment: jobSuccess is json object  which you from success key from your json response

Comment: but not giving option for jsonboject with data

Comment: I didn't  understand

Comment: can you tell how will you set jsonobject for jobsucess

Comment: i am getting exception 

org.json.JSONException: Value {"mydata":

Comment: here chat is banned for me, will you chat with me?

Comment: Unable to move in chat window, upload your json response somewhere and share link and add log cat error to your question

Comment: yes but issues is because of slash..and one more thing is my response is in Jsonobject format. i am using volley

Comment: it will work fine, slashes are jut appear when you print response

Comment: no sir, still not resolved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53458894/slash-is-not-removing-from-response-in-volley

Comment: did you check why i am getting exception

Comment: @chris check update latest in my answer, and let me know if you face any problem

Answer (score -1):

here is how you can achieve it in Kotlin.

```
val obj = JSONObject(response)

        val arrayOfArrays = obj.getJSONArray("mydata")

        repeat(arrayOfArrays.length()){index->
            val innerArray = arrayOfArrays.getJSONArray(index)
            //either get the fields by their index
            val name = innerArray.getString(0) //Ramesh
            val field = innerArray.getString(1)//Architect
            val third = innerArray.getString(2)//Surat
            val id = innerArray.getString(3)//1
            val date = innerArray.getString(4)//2011/04/25
            val price = innerArray.getString(5)//$123,123
            //or loop through the inner array
            repeat(innerArray.length()){
                //your inner array fields
            }
        }
```

suggestion:

1. ask your backend developer to provide you with a list of objects instead of array of strings.
2. use a JSON parsing library like: moshi, gson, jakson