# org.json.JSONException in volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley, jsonexception, jsonobjectrequest

I am parsing json using volley but its not working and getting error. Follwing is my code and json reponse. please help me to solve this

```
 private void getStaffList() {

        showpDialog();
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        final String url = "url";


        try {

            final JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();


            jsonObj.put("username", "test");
            jsonObj.put("password", "123456");


            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    url, jsonObj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Main response=" + response);


                    staffarraylist=new ArrayList<DataModel>();;
                    try {
                        JSONObject jobSuccess=response.getJSONObject("TABLE_DATA");
                        Log.d("TAG", "JSONObj response=" + jobSuccess);
                        JSONArray jarMyData=jobSuccess.getJSONArray("data");
                        Log.d("TAG", "JSONArray response=" + jarMyData);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jarMyData.length(); i++) {
                            JSONArray jar = jarMyData.getJSONArray(i);

                            DataModel movie = new DataModel();
                            movie.setName(jar.getString(0));
                            movie.setOccupation(jar.getString(1));
                            movie.setPlace(jar.getString(2));
                            movie.setId(jar.getString(3));
                            movie.setDate(jar.getString(4));
                            movie.setPrice(jar.getString(5));
                            staffarraylist.add(movie);
                        }
                    }catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        Log.d("JSONException",e.toString());
                    }


                    rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterHome(MainActivity.this,  staffarraylist);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);

                    hidepDialog();

                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("TAG", "JSONObj Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidepDialog();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // hide the progress dialog
                }
            });

            requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Logcat

Main response={"TABLE_DATA":"{\"data\":[[\"Tiger Nixon\",\"System Architect\",\"Edinburgh\",\"5421\",\"2011/04/25\",\"$320,800\"],[\"Garrett Winters\",\"Accountant\",....so on

D/JSONException: org.json.JSONException: Value {"data":[["Tiger Nixon","System Architect","Edinburgh","5421","2011/04/25","$320,800"],["Garrett Winters","Accountant","Tokyo","8422","2011/07/25","$

Answer (score 0):

First check that your json format is correct or not by   [clicking here](https://jsonlint.com/) and paste your json for checking. If the response is correct then use Gson. It will parse the response without any error.

Comment: response is ok, can you tell what is the use of Gson in my case? how to use.

Comment: It will convert your response into a pojo class.So you can use this class instead of converting json manually.

Comment: can you help me with that please

Comment: Copy paste your json response .It will create a java class for you put it in your project. and then add gson library to your project.

Comment: it is createing like this

public class Test
{
    private String TABLE_DATA;

    public String getTABLE_DATA ()
    {
        return TABLE_DATA;
    }

    public void setTABLE_DATA (String TABLE_DATA)
    {
        this.TABLE_DATA = TABLE_DATA;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [TABLE_DATA = "+TABLE_DATA+"]";
    }
}

how will check for data ??

Comment: Now create a class inside your project with name Test

Comment: Gson gson = new Gson();  
Test test = gson.fromJson(response, Test.class);

Comment: how to parse data array