# How to parse nested response?

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2, jsonparser

I want to parse json response receiving from server.

```
{"Status":"pass","min":103000.0,"Message":"Operation completed successfully","series":[{"data":[[1507507200000,103000.0],[1510012800000,107874.49150413179],[1512604800000,109453.64095085584],[1515369600000,115992.60554078722],[1517961600000,114557.67384347266],[1520380800000,111781.5205346012],[1523232000000,121114.55974578172],[1525651200000,126418.04557301581],[1528329600000,129649.49324900289],[1531094400000,131222.37238717882],[1533600000000,142142.39441838325],[1536278400000,142411.17969971805],[1538956800000,125147.1845640562],[1544140800000,141337.14434191343],[1546819200000,149062.2616504871],[1549497600000,150398.89724614265],[1551916800000,155610.60356124814]],"name":"Test1","type":"Line"},{"data":[[1507507200000,103000.0],[1510012800000,107800.82650460141],[1512604800000,110050.51234952305],[1515369600000,115843.2777158723],[1517961600000,116428.85968670264],[1520380800000,117524.0658796185],[1523232000000,122098.93610975571],[1525651200000,126490.48580575222],[1528329600000,129015.52592946698],[1531094400000,131998.7382591821],[1533600000000,138066.91286038296],[1536278400000,142287.2302029758],[1538956800000,136210.69656267448],[1544140800000,144444.38168584733],[1546819200000,148289.47241445977],[1549497600000,152253.57425527615],[1551916800000,155341.6134776986]],"name":"Test2","type":"Area"}]}
```

Below are the Models for response

Parent Class(Outer Json class)

```
   public class Valuation implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("series")
    private List<Series> series = new ArrayList<>();
    @SerializedName("min")
    private double min;

    public double getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public void setMin(double min) {
        this.min = min;
    }

    public List<Series> getSeries() {
        return series;
    }

    public void setSeries(List<Series> series) {
        this.series= series;
    }
}
```

Child class

Series Class

```
    public class Series implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<HashMap<Long, Double>> seriesData = new ArrayList<HashMap<Long, Double>>();

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;

    public List<HashMap<Long, Double>> getSeriesData() {
        return seriesData ;
    }

    public void setSeriesData(List<HashMap<Long, Double>> seriesData ) {
        this.seriesData = seriesData ;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

I am am not able to parse this response. How can I achieve parsing with this response?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586069/parse-json-array-without-key-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON Array without Key in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586069/parse-json-array-without-key-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy/Paste your response  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and select your parse type Jackson or gson based on it will create the model classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your model class will look like the following.

**Valuation Class**

```
public class Valuation{
    private String Status;

    private String min;

    private String Message;

     private ArrayList<Series> series;

    public String getStatus (){
        return Status;
    }

    public void setStatus (String Status){
        this.Status = Status;
    }

    public String getMin (){
        return min;
    }

    public void setMin (String min){
        this.min = min;
    }

    public String getMessage (){
        return Message;
    }

    public void setMessage (String Message){
        this.Message = Message;
    }

    public void setSeries(ArrayList<Series> series){
        this.series = series;
    }
    public ArrayList<Series> getSeries(){
        return this.series;
    }
}
```

**Series Class**

```
public class Series{
      private ArrayList<ArrayList<int>> data;

    private String name;

    private String type;

     public void setData(ArrayList<ArrayList<int>> data){
        this.data = data;
    }
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<int>> getData(){
        return this.data;
    }

    public String getName (){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType (){
        return type;
    }

    public void setType (String type){
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```