# How to fetch JSON data that does not have keys in xamarin forms

Tags: json, xamarin

How do I fetch data that does not have keys in xamarin form?
JSON example:

```
{
    "child": [
        "25400.000",
        "45500.0000",
        "45501.0000"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse JSON Array without Key in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586069/parse-json-array-without-key-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<string> child { get; set; }
}
```