# How to make data class of a JSON data if it is not having keys in Kotlin (Android studio)?

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

```
{
   "results" : [
      
        [ "5bcafde29600021147742e3a",
            "ljsdlfj",
           "ljdfl",
             "url",
             "title",
              15.2805
          ],

      [ "5bcafde29600021147742e3a",
            "ljsdlfj",
           "ljdfl",
             "url",
             "title",
              14.2805
          ],

        [ "5bcafde29600021147742e3a",
            "ljsdlfj",
           "ljdfl",
             "url",
             "title",
              13.2805
          ]
      ],
 "count": 53,
 "total": 53,
 "perpage": 10,
 "page": 0
                   }

  Although I tried making it using kotlin data class file from JSON - plugin but it resulted 
  like this - 
       
     data class store(
       val count: Int,
       val page: Int,
       val perpage: Int,
       val results: List<List<Any>>,
       val total: Int
                    )
```

See, here it created **val results: List<List>**, which i don't understand how to use in adapter. Is there any way to solve it?
Hope you understand the question, if you found trouble in getting json data [check here](https://api.nasa.gov/techtransfer/patent/?engine&api_key=DEMO_KEY)

Here's my adapter class, I need url, title and description from results (of Json Data) into pDecp, pTitle and pImg.

```
class PatentAdapter(val context: Context, val patents: List<List<Any>>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<PatentAdapter.PatentViewHolder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PatentViewHolder {

    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.patent_item, parent, false)
    return PatentViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PatentViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val patentData : List<List<Patent>> = patents as List<List<Patent>>
    holder.pDecp.text =
    holder.pTitle.text =
  

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return patents.size
}

class PatentViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var pTitle = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_patentTitle)
    var pDecp = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_patentDescription)
    var pImg = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_patentImg)
}
```

}

Comment: Show your adapter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse JSON Array without Key in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586069/parse-json-array-without-key-in-android)

Comment: @mightyWOZ check now....

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution, it will be great if you can improve it while it works for me ->

**Data class would be like this ->**

```
   data class Patent(
val count: Int,
val page: Int,
val perpage: Int,
val results: List<List<String>>,
val total: Int
 )
```

**And in adapter class we have to take the postion of array or list if we didn't have keys like this ->**

```
    class PatentAdapter(val context: Context, val patents: Patent) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<PatentAdapter.PatentViewHolder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PatentViewHolder {

    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.patent_item, parent, false)
    return PatentViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PatentViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val patentData : List<String> = patents.results[position]
    holder.pDecp.text = patentData[3]
    holder.pTitle.text = patentData[2]
    Glide.with(this.context).load(patentData[10].toString()).into(holder.pImg)


}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return patents.results.size
}

class PatentViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var pTitle = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_patentTitle)
    var pDecp = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_patentDescription)
    var pImg = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_patentImg)
}
```

}